# Getting rid of beginning and ending characters when using re.split()

Tags: regex, python-3.x, split

I am trying to understand `re.split()`, I want to ignore comma separators, periods, and dashes.

What I am not understanding is why I get an empty string at the end of my result.

And I cannot seem to figure out how to ignore say a comma.

Here is my test code:

```
sntc = 'this is a sentence total $5678 fees: expenses $123,345 why not -2345 hey.'

test = re.split('\D*', sntc) 
print(test)
```

I get the following output:

```
['', '5678', '123', '345', '2345', '']
```

Obviously, split picks up too much.  I can deal with that by using a different Regex approach, but what I can’t figure out is why `''` is on either end of the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you really want this:

```
>>> re.findall('\d+', sntc)
['5678', '123', '345', '2345']
```

Your `regex` has little problem, and can ends up like this:

```
>>> re.split('\D*', sntc)
['', '', '5', '6', '7', '8', '', '1', '2', '3', '', '3', '4', '5', '', '2', '3', '4', '5', '', '']
```

I think what you intended to do is:

```
>>> re.split('\D+', sntc)
['', '5678', '123', '345', '2345', '']
```

However, this is what `split` about, it splits things, even if it leaves `nothing`.
Consider `CSV`s, or `TAB` separated `xls` files.
It's designed like that. -- Even if no things between the commas or TABs, there're still those columns exists -- blank columns.

And the `\D+` here, it's working like the `comma` or `TAB`, it will act as a column delimiter, no matter if you have things before it or not, it will denotes a new `column` is after it.
Same thing for the last `\D+` matched contents, no matter if you have things follow it or not, it still denotes a new `column` after it.

Answer (score 0):

Because split looks for the regex to match *separators* - and `hey.` matches the regex, but also separates `2345` from the end of the string.

So what you're getting is `'2345 hey.'` being split into `'2345'` and `''`, with `' hey.'` in between them.

Similarly, if your separator was `a` and you had the string `aba` you'd get the result `['', 'b', '']` because `a` separates the beginning and end of the string from the `b` in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

[`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) is explicit about this:

> If there are capturing groups in the separator and it matches at the
>   start of the string, the result will start with an empty string. The
>   same holds for the end of the string:
>
> ```
> >>> re.split(r'(\W+)', '...words, words...')`
> ['', '...', 'words', ', ', 'words', '...', ''`
> ```

I think you better use `re.findall(r'\D+', sntc)` here.

Answer (score 0):

Than you Amber and Arount.

Here’s how I’ve implemented:

```
    whatup = sntce.replace(',', '')
#gets rid of thousands separators
testing = re.findall(r'[0-9,-.]+', whatup)
#gets rid of everything but the pos and neg numbers.
```

And I guess I don’t need the comma in the re.  I then cast the strings to numbers and off I go.